Hidden integer counter in Excel chart?
I animate 2d point moving in excel chart by a very simple cycle:
do while true
   .ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = x
   .ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = y
   doEvents
   ... some changes of (x,y) ...
loop

After 32768 steps the run-time error 1004 is thrown without next explanation. No possibility to work with Chart object more.
Any idea what's happened?
There is general behavior in any animation realized by this way. Maybe there is some hidden counter in chart counting insertion items into seriesCollection or so? Can I clean this counter?
Thanks for Your answer

Can confirm the behavior, but not explain, and I doubt that you will find any more information about that. But even if you would get some more information, it is very unlikely that you could do something against that - it's an internal implementation detail and nothing is exposed to VBA.
What I found is that if you save and close the workbook, after reopening you can continue, so that could be a solution.
My idea, however, is to copy the chart, set the copy (I name it "Template") to hidden and whenever the error occurs, delete the working chart and create a new one using the template.
With ActiveSheet
    Dim coTemplate As ChartObject, co As ChartObject
    Set coTemplate = ws.ChartObjects("ChartTemplate")
    Set co = ws.ChartObjects("Chart1")
    coTemplate.Visible = False

    Do While True
        Dim s As Series
        Set s = .ChartObjects("Chart1").chart.SeriesCollection(1)
        On Error Resume Next
        co.chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = x
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then 
             copyTemplate co, coTemplate
             Debug.print "chart recreated."
        End If
        co.chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = y
        On Error GoTo 0
        (...)
    Loop 
End With

Sub copyTemplate(co As ChartObject, coTemplate As ChartObject)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = co.Parent
    
    Dim saveLeft As Double, saveTop As Double, saveName As String
    saveLeft = co.Left
    saveTop = co.Top
    saveName = co.Name
    ' Delete chart
    co.Delete
    ' Copy the template
    coTemplate.Copy
    ws.Paste
    
    Set co = .ChartObjects(.ChartObjects.Count)
    co.Visible = True
    co.Name = saveName
    co.Left = saveLeft
    co.Top = saveTop
End Sub


Thanks for Your answer. I repaired my program using error trap and recreating the seriesCollection object in such case. But I mean it is the undocumented limit of Chart library and I hoped that it will be explained.
